# Save data of custom form in db using model

Tags: magento2, model

> **My controller file**

```
 <?php
namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Controller\Index;
use Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\DataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class  formdata extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
   protected $Data;
   protected $resultRedirect;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
       // \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result
        \Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\DataFactory  $data

    ) {
        $this->Data = $data;
        parent::__construct($context);
      //  $this->resultRedirect = $result;
    }

    public function execute(){

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        //$model = $this->DataFactory->create();
      //  $model->setData($data)->save();



        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $this->_redirect('form');
    }


}
```

> **My model file**

```
    <?php
namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
class Data extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\Data');
    }
}
```

> **My resource model file**

```
    <?php
namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel;
class Data  extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb{
    public function _construct(){
        $this->_init("Dealerreferral","ref_id");
    }
}
```

> **And collection file**

```
    <?php
namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\Data;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
/**
* Define model & resource model
*/
protected function _construct()
{
$this->_init(
'Afg\Dealerreferral\Model',
'Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\Data'
);
}
}
```

> **This error I am facing**

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Afg\Dealerreferral\Controller\Index\formdata\Interceptor

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Afg\Dealerreferral\Controller\Index\formdata\Interceptor
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php:44]
#3 Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:306]
#4 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:167]
#5 Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:95]
#6 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#9 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#10 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Magestorm/ReCaptcha/Plugin/PreDispatch.php:137]
#11 Magestorm\ReCaptcha\Plugin\PreDispatch->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#13 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
</pre>
```

Comment: it may be an issue of model i guess.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this way
>
> **Model file**

**app\code\Afg\Dealerreferral\Model**

**CustomerData.php**

```
<?php


namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData as CustomerDataResourceModel;

class CustomerData extends AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomerDataResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

> **Resource model file**

**app\code\Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel**

**CustomerData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomerData extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        //palese check you table name and primary key column name
        $this->_init('Dealerreferral', 'ref_id'); 
    }
}
```

> **Collection file**

**app\code\Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\CustomerData as CustomerDataModel;
use Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerData as CustomerDataResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomerDataModel::class,
            CustomerDataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

> **Controller file**

```
<?php

namespace Afg\Dealerreferral\Controller\Index;

class  formdata extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

   protected $cutomerData;
   protected $resultRedirect;

   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Afg\Dealerreferral\Model\CustomerDataFactory  $cutomerData

    ) {
        $this->cutomerData = $cutomerData;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        //print_r($data);
        $model = $this->cutomerData->create();
        $model->setData($data);
        $model->save();
        // your save data
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($model->getData());
        exit();        
    }
}
```

> Please run magent command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```