# How to save custom table data in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, adminhtml, model, savedata

I have created a table using a Controller and Model and in that file show some data.

But i don't know how to save that data in database i have created a table in Magento 2 db.
But don't understand how to get those data and save it.

Any help is appriciated.

When i click on send it reload the page and in network it goes to 302 Found.

Comment: Please share some more details like the table name what are the fields and the code snippets where it would be easy to understand your problem and clear it soon.

Comment: I have updated my question hope it helps will you please suggest me anything @Rising

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/310465/82670

Comment: here i added sample module you can check it. i hope this helps you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317429/82670

Comment: I am not using Admin Grid for my module is it necessary to use it i have just a simple form in that a table to show the data @Msquare

Comment: No it's not necessary to use you can skip admins files.

Comment: I have updated my file it goes to 302 found @Msquare

Comment: for retrieve config values check this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87835

Comment: for 302 found plese send me your module i will check it.

Comment: I have updated my Block and and controller file and provide the path of controller in action of button but it goes to 302.
If you want i will add more files just please update me @Msquare

Comment: are doing at backend or frontend  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112237/discussion-between-prits-and-msquare).

Comment: please check links and update me.

Answer (score 0):

the method you are using is incorrect.
Magento 2 provides the UI components for your needs.
Here are some examples on how to implement a custom table backend grid and how to save it.

docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/howto/new_component_declaration.html

example:

https://webkul.com/blog/create-collection-grid-editadd-grid-row-installer-magento2/

Cheers